# I want to show Jquery UI Dialog(message) after an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, dialog

first: I want to show the returning data with an Ajax request in my Jquery UI message box. and second: in the code below the message box appears just for 1 second. I dont know why!!!!!

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      autoOpen:false,
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
           $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

    $("#customer_form").submit(function(){
      $.get("../ajax/Services.php?Add=Add, function(data){
        if (data) {
          $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<body>
  <div id="dialog-confirm" title="MY TITLE">
    <p>
      SOME TEXT <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"
                      style="float:right; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
    </p>
  </div>       
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want "SOME TEXT" to be what gets replaced with `data`, you need to wrap it in a `span` so that you can select just that element without affecting the icon next to it:

```
 <div id="dialog-confirm" title="MY TITLE">
    <p>
      <span id="dialog-text"> </span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"
                      style="float:right; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

For the second issue it's likely that what you're seeing is a new page getting loaded.

You need to prevent the `submit` action from following through and really submitting.

```
$("#customer_form").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (data) {
      $("#dialog-text").html(data);
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my second problem, now how can I show my returning data from Ajax, in the message box???

Comment: @user1336028 I added stuff about populating the dialog box too

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your code:

**MISSING** a `"` on the file path

```
$("#customer_form").submit(function(){
  $.get("../ajax/Services.php?Add=Add", function(data){
    if (data) {
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    }
  });
});
```

**To place the returned data on the dialog, you can:**

```
$("#customer_form").submit(function(){
  $.get("../ajax/Services.php?Add=Add", function(data){
    if (data) {
      $("#dialog-confirm p").append(data);
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    }
  });
});
```

Read about: [Jquery .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Is "data" returning anything?

Comment: And did you see the issue mentioned by [Alnitak](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10566414/352449)?

Comment: then how should I replace "data" with "SOME TEXT"?

Comment: You want to replace the value of `data` with _some text_ ? **Or the other way around?**